# One of the "Activity Feed" items is not ours (different domain). Links to YouTube

Tags: facebook, plugins, android-activity, widget

Occasionally our Facebook Activity feed widget will display an item that is not from our domain.  In the most recent occurence it's displaying a link to a YouTube video.  The video is certainly not part of our domain.  All of the other items are.

This seems to occur in all browsers.  It also happens regardless of your logged in state.  That is, it displays the incorrect item whether you are logged into Facebook or not.

Here is the code from our page:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/activity.php?site=today.uconn.edu&amp;width=238&amp;height=300&amp;header=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;border_color=%23f8f8f8" 
class="fbActContainer load-later"  
scrolling="no"  
frameborder="0"  
allowTransparency="true"  
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:238px; height:300px;"></iframe>
```

I also had a screenshot but, as a newbie here, I'm not allowed to post images.